# How to pass multiple destinations to Google matrix api dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I want to send one origin and multiple destinations to Google datamatrix api dynamically.
It works fine if we use pass values directly as:

```
service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [document.getElementById("origin1").value],
            destinations: ["kopargaon", "manmad"],
            ....
```

but if we push location in array and then passed to destination then it wont work. 
E.g.

```
service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [document.getElementById("origin1").value],
            destinations: [loc.toString()],
            ....
            //loc is array of locations
```

API Considers all array elements as single location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting array to string, But the destination requires array as input.

```
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
    origins: [document.getElementById("origin1").value],              
    destinations: [loc],   // .ToString converts array to string, Hence removed
    ....
    //loc is array of locations
```

Comment: my array declaration is `var loc= new Array();`

Comment: @VaibhavrajRohamRaJ Can you create jsFiddle of your code. It will help in better soln

Comment: it will considor `loc()` as a function

Comment: What is the data/value in loc

Comment: Also add HTML to trigger jQuery